# Mouse over javascript function is not working on another PC except mine

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have this code to change the image into a gif when the user hover the mouse to that image, I'm using two different file type, a png when it's static then when hover it turns into another file that is a gif. I'm coding inside the header file of the stack theme on wordpress, it works perfectly on my PC but if we open it on another PC the hover effect won't work.

I tried another code it's a jQuery also but it still doesn't work on another PC

This is the code for the div

```html
<div class="vdw" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 2px; background: #FDFAF3;">
  <p class="vdw" style="padding-top: 2em;">
    <img id="static" class="border--round aligncenter static vdw" width="355" height="220" src="http://codingcom.lumikha.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Book_4_reverseAnimation.png" data-src="http://codingcom.lumikha.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Book_4_reverseAnimation.png" data-hover="/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Book_4-1.gif" alt="Image">
  </p> 
  <p class="" style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 5em;">
    <span style="font-family: 'PT Sans'; font-size: 14pt;" class=""><strong class="">Safe &amp; Secure</strong></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

then here's my JavaScript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($){
    $("#static").mouseover(function () {
      $(this).attr('src', $(this).data("hover"));
    }).mouseout(function () {
      $(this).attr('src', $(this).data("src"));
    });

  });
</script>
```

then I tried this code too

```
 jQuery(function($){
   $("#static").on({
     mouseenter: function(){
       $(this).attr('src','http://codingcom.lumikha.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Book_4-1.gif');
     },
     mouseleave: function(){
        $(this).attr('src','http://codingcom.lumikha.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Book_4_reverseAnimation.png');
     }
   });
 });
```

Comment: Did you clear the cache on the other PC to ensure it's not just using a stale version of the code? Are both PCs using the same browser (and version)?

Comment: if you are using Chrome .. make sure you have hard loaded it

Comment: I did no clear the cache sir @TylerRoper since the website will be live soon I need it to work on every browser and since most of the user won't be clearing their cache then i need it to work without clearing the cache..I code on my PC and it work perfectly find on my end but if another user open the website the javascript won't work they need to wait for like 1min or so for the effect to work..

Comment: So wait, it "doesn't work", or it works, but delayed? Those are very different problems. Also, if caching were the issue, you'd have to implement something to refresh the cached file; you wouldn't rely on all users clearing their cache.

Comment: @TylerRoper to make it clear one works but delayed, in my PC it works fine, in other PC with big screen..

Answer (score 0):

By the way you can do it simply in CSS.

```
<div>
 <img class="static" src="http://codingcom.lumikha.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Book_4_reverseAnimation.png">
 <img class="gif" src="http://codingcom.lumikha.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Book_4-1.gif">
</div>

<style>
.gif{
display:none;
}
div:hover .static{
display:none;
}
div:hover .gif{
display:block;
} 
</style>
```

Comment: I tried this one but the problem is wordpress has a default div on their theme so the code seem to work but the 2nd image is on the bottom basically they did not change it just that the hover added a second image below